# Why isn't the icon showing up on top?

Tags: css, fluid

im trying to make a gallery out of boxes of solid color and an icon on top of it, and when you hover over the box, the solid color changes to a image, and the icon remains.

I actually got a decent answer to this on a previous question, but didn't work with keeping the site responsive. So i thought i figured out a way of going around this, but i cant seem to find a way to make the icon stay on the top.

HTML:

```
<div class="icon">
    <img src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" onmouseover="this.src='http://lolhit.com/img/ups/98581662041324299463.jpeg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif'" />
</div>
```

CSS:
`.icon {
    background: url(http://loosewire.org/wp-content/uploads/blue-icon-transparent-background-500px.png) no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;

}`

I also made a fiddle, and just to be clear, it's the `.icon` that i want to be on top at all times, with box having the ability to change to image on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/baardkolstad/2L44J/

The images used are only for presentation purposes, not the actual images that are going to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my final solution for this was to put the icon in an img tag and use the two photos as backgrounds in the CSS. In that way, you have the icon centered at all times, while staying on top.

Thanks for all the help on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at using a z-index here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Take note that this only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).  This is also on the above web page.